# Arduino read two rotary encoders not giving desired output

Tags: arduino, embedded

I'm trying to read two hall effect rotary encoders on 2 separate motors which will be used for my robot's wheels. I've decided to use interrupts on the A channels of both encoders and get the direction by reading the B channel input in the ISR.

For some reason the serial output when I spin the right motor output shaft magnets gives me:

R 1 R 0 R 1 R 0 R 1 R 0 R 1 R 0 R 1 R 0 R 1

And when i spin the left one, it gives me:

L -1 L -2 L -1 L -2 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4 L -3 L -4

Both were spun in the same clockwise direction. Could anyone please tell me why my pulse counter isn't incrementing as it should be?

FYI, I'm using an Arduino pro mini. I've actually attempted using interrupts on both A and B channels on both motors using pins 2,3 and 0,1 for left and right encoders. But for some reason the right encoder wasn't outputting correctly. Only the left one did. I thought using pins 0 and 1 may be affecting the serial output to USB hence I moved to using 1 interrupts for each encoder, but it's not working as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've posted my code below.

```
// variables for encoders
// left
int AChnl_L = 3, BChnl_L = 7;
int lastPulse_L = 0, newPulse_L = 0;
bool BSIG_L = LOW;
int pulseCount_L = 0, prevPulseCount_L = 0;
int revs_L = 0;
// right
int AChnl_R = 2, BChnl_R = 8;
int lastPulse_R = 0, newPulse_R = 0;
bool BSIG_R = LOW;
int pulseCount_R = 0, prevPulseCount_R = 0;
int revs_R = 0;

void setup()
{
    // setup interrupt on left encoder channel A
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AChnl_L), ARise_L, RISING);
    // setup interrupt on right encoder channel A
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AChnl_R), ARise_R, RISING);

    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    readEncoder_L();
    readEncoder_R();

    if (pulseCount_L != prevPulseCount_L)
    {
        Serial.println("L");
        Serial.println(pulseCount_L);
        prevPulseCount_L = pulseCount_L;
    }
    if (pulseCount_R != prevPulseCount_R)
    {
        Serial.println("R");
        Serial.println(pulseCount_R);
        prevPulseCount_R = pulseCount_R;
    }
}

/*
clears incoming serial buffer
*/
void serialFlush()
{
    while(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        Serial.read();
    }
}

/* 
function for incrementing/decrementing signal pulses for left encoder
*/
void readEncoder_L()
{
    // rotated CW
    if(newPulse_L > lastPulse_L)
    {
        pulseCount_L++;
        lastPulse_L = newPulse_L;
    }
    // rotated CCW
    else if(newPulse_L < lastPulse_L)
    {
        pulseCount_L--;
        lastPulse_L = newPulse_L;
    }
}

/* 
function for incrementing/decrementing signal pulses for right encoder
*/
void readEncoder_R()
{
    // rotated CW
    if(newPulse_R > lastPulse_R)
    {
        pulseCount_R++;
        lastPulse_R = newPulse_R;
    }
    // rotated CCW
    else if(newPulse_R < lastPulse_R)
    {
        pulseCount_R--;
        lastPulse_R = newPulse_R;
    }
}

/*
ISR for rising pulse on channel A left
if B == 1 then CW, if B == 0 then CCW
swap to falling edge ISR
*/
void ARise_L()
{
    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AChnl_L));
    BSIG_L = digitalRead(BChnl_L);
    // if ASIG_L == 1 & BSIG_L == 1 then CW
    if (BSIG_L == HIGH)
    {
        newPulse_L++;
    }
    // if ASIG_L == 1 & BSIG_L == 0 then CCW
    if (BSIG_L == LOW)
    {
        newPulse_L--;
    }
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AChnl_L), AFall_L, FALLING);
}

/*
ISR for falling pulse on channel A left
if B == 0 then CW, if B == 1 then CCW
swap to rising edge ISR
*/
void AFall_L()
{
    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AChnl_L));
    BSIG_L = digitalRead(BChnl_L);
    // if ASIG_L == 0 & BSIG_L == 0 then CW
    if (BSIG_L == LOW)
    {
        newPulse_L++;
    }
    // if ASIG_L == 0 & BSIG_L == 1 then CCW
    if (BSIG_L == HIGH)
    {
        newPulse_L--;
    }
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AChnl_L), ARise_L, FALLING);
}

/*
ISR for rising pulse on channel A right
if B == 1 then CW, if B == 0 then CCW
swap to falling edge ISR
*/
void ARise_R()
{
    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AChnl_R));
    BSIG_R = analogRead(BChnl_R);
    // if ASIG_R == 1 & BSIG_R == 1 then CW
    if (BSIG_R == HIGH)
    {
        newPulse_R++;
    }
    // if ASIG_R == 1 & BSIG_R == 0 then CCW
    if (BSIG_R == LOW)
    {
        newPulse_R--;
    }
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AChnl_R), AFall_R, FALLING);
}

/*
ISR for falling pulse on channel A right
if B == 0 then CW, if B == 1 then CCW
swap to rising edge ISR
*/
void AFall_R()
{
    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AChnl_R));
    BSIG_R = analogRead(BChnl_R);
    // if ASIG_R == 0 & BSIG_R == 0 then CW
    if (BSIG_R == LOW)
    {
        newPulse_R++;
    }
    // if ASIG_R == 0 & BSIG_R == 1 then CCW
    if (BSIG_R == HIGH)
    {
        newPulse_R--;
    }
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(AChnl_R), ARise_R, FALLING);
}
```

Comment: *"isn't incrementing as it should be"* ...  It will help if you give an example of the expected behaviour.  Having one negative and one positive is probably desirable when the wheels are opposed, because then +ve and -ve correspond to forward and backward rather then clockwise and counter-clockwise.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting clean, non-bouncing edges?  What is the purpose of detaching and reattaching the interrupt in the ISRs?  Arduino does not by default enable interrupt nesting and an interrupt cannot interrupt itself in any case.  There is a much simpler logic possible:  On *Any B Edge* : `count += (A==B)? 1 : -1 ;` and on *Any A Edge* `count += (A==B) ? -1 : 1 ;`.  Avoid repeating the code for left and right - write a single function and pass the L and R counter in by reference for example; if you need left and right reversed, you can do that at a higher level.